# JAVA + print all ext args

Tags: java

when I get some args as "AHG dvds 43 56 PP 098 $$$ ###"

and I want to print all args as the following , 
but its not work - how to fix that?
and how to set all args in one string?

```
  static public void main(String[] args) 

    {

       .
       .


       System.out.println("ARGS= "+ args  );

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 System.out.print ("ARGS= ");
 for (String arg: args)
     System.out.print (arg + " ");
 System.out.println();
```

Comment: the previos example better -:)

Comment: @david thanks but I noticed that he had spaces separating his args. My previous relied on Arrays.toString(), which adds commas.

Answer (score 3):

`args[]` is an array. The `toString()` method of arrays is not overriden from `Object`. So you have to iterate over all the elements if you want to create a String from them. That is what `Arrays.toString()` does.